# Is it possible for a template class to only accept implementers of a specific interface?

Tags: java

Have a template class:

```
class Foo <T> {

    private T bar;

    public Foo(T bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

Have an interface:

```
interface SomeInterface {
    public void boom();
}
```

I want `Foo` to only accept types of classes that implement the interface `SomeInterface`.

Intuitively, I wanted something like this:

```
class Foo <T implements SomeInterface>
```

But apparently this doesn't work.

Is it possible for a template class to only accept implementers of a specific interface?

---

This is because I want to call certain methods on `this.bar`. Methods that happen to be defined in `SomeInterface`.

Comment: Use `extends` instead of `implements`

Comment: @user3580294: Thank you. That wasn't intuitive.

Comment: No problem. And in case it's helpful later, you can specify multiple bounds for a type parameter using `&`: `<T extends ClassX & InterfaceA & InterfaceB>`. Only restriction is that if there's a class in there it has to be listed first (I think), and a type can only extend one class.